# How to solve this Dependencies apt --fix-broken install

Tags: debian, installation, kali-linux, dependencies

When I use the command

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

I get the following errors:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Correcting dependencies... failed.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libhogweed4 : Depends: libnettle6 (= 3.3-1+b1) but 3.4-1 is installed
>   mana-toolkit : Depends: dnsmasq but it is not installable
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
>   E: Unable to correct dependencies

I am unable to install anything because of this.
What can I do?

Answer (score 24):

This is not a simple problem, and I faced a similar one just a minute ago. I solved it by running  (a variation on):

- `dpkg --force-all --configure -a`
- `dpkg --purge --force-depends libnettle6` ([cf. this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/880422/411415))
- `apt --fix-broken install`
- `apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 7):

The solution above solved only part of the problem in my case, i had to purge all the faulty packages. My issue was like so:

```
root@MrApollos:/var/cache/apt/archives/partial# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kali-desktop-base : Depends: kali-themes-common (= 2021.2.3) but 2021.2.1 is installed
 kali-themes : Depends: kali-themes-common (= 2021.2.3) but 2021.2.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

in my case, i had to run

`dpkg --force-all --configure -a`

`dpkg --purge --force-depends kali-desktop-base` to remove the first faulty package

`dpkg --purge --force-depends kali-themes` to remove the second faulty package
`dpkg --purge --force-depends kali-themes-common` to remove the third faulty package

then `apt-get -f install`

and finally `apt update & apt-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Restart, close other (automatic) updates that are running in background, then try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: How is this better than other answers?

Comment: I had tried the above solutions but they did not work as I missed that automatic updates were running in the background. In this solution, this has been stated clearly.